# Problems using the Google Cloud go library for logging

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sdk

I am trying to use `import "cloud.google.com/go/logging"` with the Go example code found here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library . With go1.15.6, I tried these things:

````sh
$ go get -u cloud.google.com/go/logging

# many errors about dependencies, so
$ go get -u github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp
$ go get -u golang.org/x/sync/semaphore

# then I can get through this one
$ go get -u cloud.google.com/go/logging

# for further amusement, these two fail with what seems to be a compiler error
$ go get cloud.google.com/go/storage
$ go get cloud.google.com/go/iam

# Then trying to build my code using Logging:
$ go build -i -v
cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2
# cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:269:62: undefined: logging.ListBucketsRequest
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:310:60: undefined: logging.GetBucketRequest
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:310:114: undefined: logging.LogBucket
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:328:63: undefined: logging.CreateBucketRequest
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:328:120: undefined: logging.LogBucket
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:354:63: undefined: logging.UpdateBucketRequest
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:354:120: undefined: logging.LogBucket
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:374:63: undefined: logging.DeleteBucketRequest
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:825:14: undefined: logging.LogBucket
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:840:65: undefined: logging.LogBucket
../../go/src/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:374:63: too many errors```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JimB (https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) who provided a comment
at this question [Problems installing GCP go library for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604118/problems-installing-gcp-go-library-for-logging) (which was rudely closed by people who don't want to try to help) that pointed in the direction of this answer.

The problem here is that you are not using modules and the Google Cloud library only supports use that way. This means you do not use `go get ...` at all, **despite the documentation** at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go . Instead, start by creating this go.mod file:

```
module example.com/mymod

go 1.15

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/logging v1.1.2
)
```

Then, run `go build -i -v` which will install all the required modules.